# How to use the TensorFlow dataset API with unknown shapes properly?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

I've been trying for several hours to complete this task with no success.

I have a very large dataset which is comprised of the following structure:
[image]

I want to split this data into X and Y (and pass Y to `tf.to_categorical`) as in the picture using the `tf.data.Dataset` API, but unfortunately every attempt of me trying to use it has ended up with some kind of error.

How do I use `tf.data.Dataset` to:

1. Split each row to x and y.
2. Convert Y to categorical with `tf.to_categorical`.
3. Split the dataset into batches.
4. Feed my model with the dataset.

My current attempt:

```
def map_sequence():
    for sequence in input_sequences:
        yield sequence[:-1], keras.utils.to_categorical(sequence[-1], total_words)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(map_sequence,
                                        (tf.int32, tf.int32),
                                        (tf.TensorShape(title_length-1), tf.TensorShape(total_words)))
```

But when I try to train my model with the following code:

```
inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(title_length-1, ))

x = keras.layers.Embedding(total_words, 32)(inputs)
x = keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))(x)
x = keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(64))(x)
predictions = keras.layers.Dense(total_words, activation='softmax')(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
model.compile('Adam', 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(dataset)
```

I am getting this error: `ValueError: Shapes (32954, 1) and (65, 32954) are incompatible`

Comment: Please provide some more information about your problem. Specify what is `input_sequences`, how you are batching the dataset and where is the error happening.

Comment: @jdehesa I updated the post. I currently do not batch my dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a similar problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61959517/1782792). Keras expects the dataset that you give to produce batches, not individual examples. Since you are giving it two one-dimensional vectors at a time, Keras interprets that each of these is a batch of examples with one feature. So, your `X` data, which has 65 elements, is interpreted as a batch of 65 examples with a single feature (a 65x1 tensor). This fixes the batch size to 65. The output of the model has then shape 65x32,954 (which I assume is the value of `total_words`). But your `Y` vector, with 32,954 elements, is again interpreted as a batch of 32,954 with one features (32,954x1 tensor). These two things don't match, hence the error. You should be able to fix it by simply making a new dataset with [`batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch) before passing it to `fit`.

In any case, if you `input_sequences` is a NumPy array, as it seems to be, your method to produce the dataset is not really good, as using a generator will be really slow. This is a better way to do the same:

```py
def map_sequence(sequence):
    # Using tf.one_hot instead of keras.utils.to_categorical
    # because we are working with TensorFlow tensors now
    return sequence[:-1], tf.one_hot(sequence[-1], total_words)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(input_sequences)
dataset = dataset.map(map_sequence)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

Comment: Also, what is the difference between `one_hot` and `to_categorical`?

Comment: @Tomergt45 They do the same thing, but I think `to_categorical` is meant for NumPy arrays, as a preprocessing step of NumPy data, whereas `one_hot` is a TensorFlow operation for tensors. If you do the transformation as part of the dataset pipeline, then you need to use TensorFlow operations. With `from_generator`, since you are working only with NumPy arrays in your `map_sequence`, `to_categorical` works there.